# Getting previous year values

Tags: oracle

If I had a table structure like this :

```
id | product name | sales dollars | projection dollars | year
```

And had data like this :

```
1 | tv | 334600 | 452000 | 2015
2 | pc | 929492 | 779564 | 2015
3 | tv | 222232 | 432134 | 2014
```

How can I get results into single row like this :

```
product name | current year sales dollars | previous year sales dollars
```

And resulting in this :

```
tv | 334600 | 222232
pc | 929492 | 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a simple case of a conditional aggregate:

```
select product_name, 
       sum(case when year = 2014 then sales_dollars end) as previous_year_sales,
       sum(case when year = 2015 then sales_dollars end) as this_year_sales
from the_table
group by product_name;
```